# Printing address a pointer points to, value the address points to, and the address of the pointer itself

Tags: c, pointers

I wrote a little program to familiarize myself with pointers and relations between them a little more. In order to do this I wrote a small piece of code that just declares and initializes an integer `a`, then declares a pointer `*p` to the address of `a` and then goes on deeper to assign a pointer to a pointer `*pp` and so on so far up to `****pppp`. If I understood pointers correctly a pointer to a pointer to a ... basically works like this:

```
Address of pointer (or integer) itself: 0x7fff08d1c658    0x7fff08d1c660    0x7fff08d1c668    0x7fff08d1c670    0x7fff08d1c67c
                                              ↑                 ↑                  ↑                ↑                 ↑ 
                                             pppp     -->      ppp       -->      pp      -->       p       -->       a = 42
                                              ↓                 ↓                  ↓                ↓                 
Address pointer points to:              0x7fff08d1c660    0x7fff08d1c668    0x7fff08d1c670    0x7fff08d1c67c
```

The addresses on the diagonal have to be identical because the previous pointer always points to the address of the next pointer which it has been assigned. Now I want to check this in a program using `printf()` calls and here I am unsure if the way I print the address the more elaborate pointers `**pp`, `***ppp`, and `****pppp` point to and how I print the addresses of these pointers themselves are correct. Could someone point out possible mistakes? Here is the code followed by its output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a;
    int *p;
    int **pp;
    int ***ppp;
    int ****pppp;

    a = 42;

    /* Take the address of a */
    p = &a;

    /* Take the address of p */
    pp = &p;

    /* Take the address of pp */
    ppp = &pp;


    /* Take the address of ppp */
    pppp = &ppp;

    printf("Address of int &a:                             %p\n", &a);
    printf("value of a:                                    %d\n\n", a);

    printf("Address where p points to via (void *)p:       %p\n", (void *)p);
    printf("Value that *p points to via *p:                %d\n", *p);
    printf("Address of *p itself via (void *)&p:           %p\n\n", (void *)&p);

    printf("Address where pp points to via (void *)pp:     %p\n", (void *)pp);
    printf("Value that **pp points to via **pp:            %d\n", **pp);
    printf("Address of **pp itself via (void *)&pp:        %p\n\n", (void *)&pp);

    printf("Address where ppp points to via (void *)ppp:   %p\n", (void *)ppp);
    printf("Value that ***ppp points to via ***ppp:        %d\n", ***ppp);
    printf("Address of ***ppp itself via (void *)&ppp:     %p\n\n", (void *)&ppp);

    printf("Address where pppp points to via (void *)pppp: %p\n", (void *)pppp);
    printf("Value that ****pppp points to via ****pppp:    %d\n", ****pppp);
    printf("Address of ****pppp itself via (void *)&pppp:  %p\n", (void *)&pppp);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

---

Output:

---

```
Address of int &a:                             0x7fff08d1c67c
value of a:                                    42

Address where p points to via (void *)p:       0x7fff08d1c67c
Value that *p points to via *p:                42
Address of *p itself via (void *)&p:           0x7fff08d1c670

Address where pp points to via (void *)pp:     0x7fff08d1c670
Value that **pp points to via **pp:            42
Address of **pp itself via (void *)&pp:        0x7fff08d1c668

Address where ppp points to via (void *)ppp:   0x7fff08d1c668
Value that ***ppp points to via ***ppp:        42
Address of ***ppp itself via (void *)&ppp:     0x7fff08d1c660

Address where pppp points to via (void *)pppp: 0x7fff08d1c660
Value that ****pppp points to via ****pppp:    42
Address of ****pppp itself via (void *)&pppp:  0x7fff08d1c658
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. There is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: There were different ways mentioned in different stackoverflow answers and on the internet to print out the address of pointers ithemselves that I was really unsure whether my logic on how to print them is correct.

Comment: Your program looks fine to me. Just remember that when you need to print pointers(addresses) use `%p`.

Comment: You need to use `%p` to print out pointers and the argument should be of type `(void *)` .. That is the only change

Comment: But it is always sufficient to simply cast the pointer via `(void *)` followed by the pointer no matter how deep the level is? Meaning if I had a pointer `*****ppppp` and wanted to print its address I would use `printf("%p", (void *)ppppp);`.

Comment: @brauner Yes no matter what is the depth a pointer is a pointer

Comment: @Gopi and @CoolGuy unless I want to print its value then I would need to use `%d` because I am printing an integer.

Comment: I did that, I just misinterpreted your comment "You need to use %p to print out pointers [...]". I read it as a general statement not one specific to addresses. Sorry.

Comment: @Gopi , `%d` expects an `int`, not `int*`.

Comment: @brauner , It is better to use the cast `void*` here too:`printf("Address of int &a:%p\n", &a);` as `%p` expects an argument f type `void*`. There won't cause any trouble if you remove the casts too. Some compilers may complain though.

Comment: Although this is a very well-asked question, it probably belongs on code review rather than here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is mostly correct: you understand that `printf` prints the value of pointers with the `%p` conversion specifier. The actual output is implementation specific but can be parsed back into a pointer value by `scanf` with the same `%p` specifier.

There is one small detail you got wrong in `printf("Address of int &a: %p\n", &a);`: pointers should always be converted to `void *` when passed to `printf` as the value to convert for the `%p` specifier. The reason for this is subtle: on some architectures, pointers to different types may have a different representation, including a different size, and may be passed to `printf` in a different way.  Converting the pointer to `void *` ensures that it will be passed in the form and manner expected by the `printf` function.

This conversion is not automatic as `printf` takes a variable number of arguments of different types, these arguments are passed in a manner specific to `vararg` functions: for instance `float` values are converted to and passed as `double`, but various pointer types are not converted to `void *`, so you must write this conversion explicitly with a `(void *)` cast.

Examples of architectures with different pointer representations tend to be less popular nowadays, but older programmers may remember the days of `near` and `far` pointers and the various memory models where function and data pointers had a different size.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm 90% sure that this code will compile+run without the cast to `(void *)` with recent versions of GCC and relatively modern language settings (although it will warn you).

Comment: As far as I can see I already casted all pointers via `(void *)` in my code (except the address of the array which @CoolGuy pointed out). So I'm not quite sure where I got that wrong. (Removing the casts would issue a warning with `-pedantic` passed to `gcc`.)

Comment: @brauner: sorry about that, I wrote *one small detail* where I should have been more explicit.  I updated the answer.  My point was also to explain the rationale for the need to cast pointers as `(void *)`